# How to find relative URL of a document library using CSOM

Tags: client-object-model

To upload a file using File.SaveBinaryDirect you have to know the server relative URL of the document library you're working with.

[Example from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee956524.aspx#SP2010ClientOMOpenXml_Uploading) :-

```
ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://intranet.contoso.com");
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("NewDocument.docx", FileMode.Open))
{
   ClientOM.File.SaveBinaryDirect(clientContext,
            "/Shared Documents/NewDocument.docx", fileStream, true);
}
```

How can you determine a Document Libraries url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
docLib = Context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("Your Doclib Name");

Context.Load(docLib);
Context.Load(docLib.RootFolder);
Context.ExecuteQuery();

string serverRelativeUrl = docLib.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl;
```

Comment: There has *got* to be a better way to do this. I'm trying to upload a document FAST. That's why I'm using SaveBinaryDirect. This is SLOOOOOOOOOOOW.